# CoordinatorLayout layout_anchorGravity not working?

Tags: android-layout, layout, android-designer

I am trying to make a layout design .In which i set **anchorGravity** of two views card view and fab.
but fab is correct position but the card view not correct position.
I also attach two images for **explanation**.
*Why does it happens ?*
**How can I Solve it ?**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_done_24"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/left_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        app:tint="@color/colorPrimary" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_category"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_done_24"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/right_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right">

</com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/account_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/smallFont"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/accout_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="title"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/account_amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="@string/amount"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cat_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cat_title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="sub title"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: out put of xml]
[image: want to achieve the output]

I am try different solution but can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying and anchor gravity of `top|right` will position a view *centered* on the top/right corner of the anchor view. But, if the anchor view butts up against a side of the coordinator layout, the view that is being anchored will shift inward. Here is an example:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/left_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

This is like your FAB. Everything seems to behave. Now lets shrink the width of the *LinearLayout* and move it down to the vertical center of the layout to move it away from the sides of the *CoordinatorLayout*. (The change in width and moving to the vertical center are the only changes to the layout.)

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_layout"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/left_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

This is what the anchoring specified does if it doesn't run into one of the sides of the *CoordinatorLayout*.

If we add `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to the view then this is what we see:

[image]

That is better but where are the margins? And why does that work (sort of) anyway?

If you can, I suggest that you wrap the `left_layout` *LinearLayout* in a *FrameLayout* and use layout gravity to position the view.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout x
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_layout"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]